# How to get column name as header in MYSQL Pivot table in php HTML table?

Tags: php, mysqli, pivot-table

Here is my PHP code. I get the output result but cannot get the header dynamically. How to do that in PHP?.

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//$sql = "SELECT * FROM test_pivot";
$sql = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COLOR = 'White' THEN NUM_AVAIL else 0 end) AVAILABLE_WHITE, SUM(CASE WHEN COLOR = 'Blue' THEN NUM_AVAIL else 0 end) AVAILABLE_BLUE, SUM(CASE WHEN COLOR = 'Blue' OR COLOR = 'White' THEN NUM_AVAIL else 0 end) AVAILABLE_TOTAL FROM test_pivot";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
 echo "<table border='1' cellpadding=10>";
 echo "<tr><th>White</th><th>Blue</th><th>Total</th>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["AVAILABLE_WHITE"]. " </td><td>" . $row["AVAILABLE_BLUE"]. "</td><td> " . $row["AVAILABLE_TOTAL"]." </td></tr>";
    }
 echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Below is the output. Now the header is static. How to get header dynamically?.
[Pivot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jf2L.png)

Comment: `foreach ($row as $key => $value)`

Comment: Thanks.. I got the header but when i run the code `foreach($row as $key => $value){ print_r($key); echo "<tr><th>".$key."</th></tr>"; //print_r($value); echo "<tr><td>".$value." </td></tr>"; }` I got everything vertically.

Comment: So fix your markup. YOu're closing `tr` too early.

Comment: I Want the Output like in the Pivot Picture.

Comment: So do it, what's the problem?